# Запись ветвления xml в массив

Tags: php, simplexml

Есть в XML ветвления, например: "genre" и "country", у которых "дети" с названием "name". В рамках учебного курса хочу записать все жанры фильма в один массив, чтоб в дальнейшем преобразовать его в строку функцией `implode` и записать в базу данных.

Перепробывал много вариантов, один из них:

```
$filmTitle = null;
$filmTitleOriginal = null;
$filmYear = null;
$filmCountry[] = null;
$filmGenre[] = null;
$filmPoster = null;

foreach ($xml as $movieKey => $movie) {
    $filmTitle = $movie->title_russian;
    $filmTitleOriginal = $movie->title_original;
    $filmYear = $movie->year;

    foreach ($movie->country->children() as $countryKey => $country) {
        $filmCountry[] = $country;
    }

    foreach ($movie->genre->children() as $genreKey => $genre) {
        $filmGenre[] = $genre;
    }

    foreach ($movie->poster->big->attributes() as $posterKey => $poster) {
        $filmPoster = $poster;
    }

    echo $filmTitle . '<br>'
    . $filmTitleOriginal . '<br>'
    . $filmYear . '<br>'
    . implode(', ', $filmCountry) . '<br>'
    . implode(', ', $filmGenre) . '<br>'
    . $filmPoster . '<br>';
}
```

Файл XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
  <movie>
    <id>154054</id>
    <type>movie</type>
    <title_russian>Джой</title_russian>
    <title_original>Joy</title_original>
    <year>2015</year>
    <runtime>0</runtime>
    <poster>
      <small url="http://c.cinemate.cc/media/m/4/5/154054/0.small.jpg"/>
      <medium url="http://c.cinemate.cc/media/m/4/5/154054/0.medium.jpg"/>
      <big url="http://c.cinemate.cc/media/m/4/5/154054/0.big.jpg"/>
    </poster>
    <url>http://cinemate.cc/movie/154054/</url>
    <country>
      <name>США</name>
    </country>
    <genre>
      <name>биография</name>
      <name>драма</name>
      <name>комедия</name>
    </genre>
  </movie>
  <movie>
    <id>159513</id>
    <type>movie</type>
    <title_russian>Лазурный берег</title_russian>
    <title_original>By the Sea</title_original>
    <year>2015</year>
    <runtime>0</runtime>
    <poster>
      <small url="http://c.cinemate.cc/media/m/3/1/159513/0.small.jpg"/>
      <medium url="http://c.cinemate.cc/media/m/3/1/159513/0.medium.jpg"/>
      <big url="http://c.cinemate.cc/media/m/3/1/159513/0.big.jpg"/>
    </poster>
    <url>http://cinemate.cc/movie/159513/</url>
    <country>
      <name>США</name>
    </country>
    <genre>
      <name>драма</name>
      <name>мелодрама</name>
    </genre>
  </movie>
</response>
```

---

Как можно решить данный вопрос?

Comment: если вы планируете осуществлять какой-либо поиск или фильтрацию по жанру, то не надо записывать их в базу как строку через запятую.

Comment: нет, в планах нет осуществления никакого реального функционала, это в рамках курса, поэтому использую преобразование в строку, дабы закрепить знания, дальше буду двигаться в другом направлении, но автор курса избегает children`ов, поэтому решил сам разобраться.